# opening files with sequential titles

Tags: python

I am trying to open a number of files of the form name_1.dat, name_2.dat etc. in a loop.  If I just write

```
for j in range(1,50):
    in_file=open(name+j+".dat", "r")
```

I get the error "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" which I sort of understand.  I tried changing this to

```
for j in range(1,50):
    in_file=open(sys.argv[1]+j.to_eng_string()+".dat", "r")
```

but now I get the error `"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_eng_string'"` which again I can sort of understand.  Having only very minor knowledge of python I am at a loss for what to do.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: > Any suggestions? < Yes - read some Python tutorials: [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) or [this](http://www.diveintopython.net/)

Comment: You can use `str(j)` to convert it. You are opening all the files in the same variable, I hope you are doing something in the for with then and closing the file afterwards.

Comment: Just one more thing, `range` works fine for your code. Although, I would suggest you to read about `range vs xrange` in python.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `j` to a `str` before concatenating it to other strings. One way to construct a string from variables of different types is to use `format`, though there are many approaches:

```
for j in range(1,50):
    in_file=open("{}_{}.dat".format(name, j), "r")
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an underscore character between the file prefix and the number in the OP's attempts.

Comment: You're right, but he does say the files are of the format name_1.dat, name_2.data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
for j in range(1,50):
  in_file=open("%s_%i.dat"%(sys.argv[1],j.to_eng_string()), "r")
```

You might also look at using `os.listdir` from [the `os` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here show you how to generate the strings that match the pattern of the file names. If, suppose, the file named `name35.dat` is not there you will need to catch that exception.

Here, I am looking at the files that actually exist by using [glob](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html) for ALL the files that match that pattern:

```
import glob
print glob.glob('name[0-9]*.dat')
```

Use a regex to limit to some subset:

```
import re, glob, sys
def expand(x,lo=0,hi=sys.maxint): 
    return lo<=int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0))<=hi

# all files that match 'name1.dat' to 'name50.dat' inclusive
print [e for e in glob.glob('name[0-9]*.dat') if expand(e, 1, 50)]
```

Now you have a list of files that exist and match your given pattern.